# best linux distro for back-end and dev-ops

Tags: linux, backend, devops

I am newbie Back-end & DevOps Developer, some people said to me that if you want to become a good developer in those fields, you should be able to run on a linux servers and etc.

Which Linux Distros Best in the long run if I were to become a Back-end/DevOps Engineer?

Comment: If one of them would be best, why would anyone bother with others? The conclusion is that none of them is "best" and "best" is subjective or "best" specific to the measurement method _you_ have chosen. Use the one that is "best" for you. If you do not know which one, try each and every "big" one like Ubuntu, OpenSuse, CentOS, Fedora, Archlinux and decide for yourself after trying them all. In devops, RedHat is important - CentOS is the "free" version, but it _will_ be intimidating for daily use.

Comment: @KamilCuk, Yes, I would totally crash a  company server because I want try a another Linux Distro